# Is the use of a non-trainable weight equivalent to the use of a Python variable in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a piece of code (not mine) that defines a non-trainable variable that is used to define another property of the layer, which looks something like

```
initial_weight_val = 1.0
w = my_layer.add_weight(name=layer.name + '/my_weight', shape=(),
                       initializer=tf.initializers.constant(initial_weight_val), 
                       trainable=False)
# Use w to set another parameter of the layer.
my_layer.the_parameter = some_function(w)
```

Please, do not tell me what a non-trainable variable is (Of course, I know what it is?), which is also discussed in [What is the definition of a non-trainable parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47312219/3924118).

However, given that `w` will not be changed (I think), I don't get why someone would define such a variable, rather than simply using the Python variable `initial_weight_val` directly, especially when using TensorFlow 2.0 (which is my case and the only case I am interested in). Of course, one possibility would be that this variable could become trainable, in case one needs it to be trainable later, but why should one anticipate this, anyway?

Can I safely use `initial_weight_val` to define `the_parameter`, i.e. pass `initial_weight_val` to `some_function` rather than `w`?

I am concerned with this issue because I cannot save a model with a variable, because I get the error "variable is not JSON serializable" (Keras and TF are so buggy, btw!), so I was trying to understand the equivalence between user-defined non-trainable variables and Python variables.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that this value doesn't change at all, and that it's a single value.
Then yes, you can use a Python var (if a python var is compatible with the function that uses this `w`).

In which case, you'd put that `initial_weight_val` both in the `__init__` and in the `get_config` methods of the layer in order for it to be properly saved.

Now, if the function only accepts tensors, but you're still sure that this value will not change at all, then you can on `call` make `w = tf.constant(self.initial_weight_val)`. You still have the value in `__init__` and in `get_config` as a python var.

Finally, if this value, although non-trainable is changing, or if it's a tensor with many elements, then you'd better let it be a weight. (Non-trainable means "non trainable by backpropagation", but still allowed to be updated here and there).
There should be absolutely no problem for saving loading this weight if you defined it correctly, which should be inside `build`, with `self.add_weight(....)`, as shown in https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/ .

---

A cool Keras example that uses non-trainable but updatable weights is the `BatchNormalization` layer. The `mean` and `std` of the batches are updated every pass, but not via backpropagation (thus `trainable=False`)

Comment: Can a non-trainable weight be saved even if it is not defined inside `call` but it is defined with `add_weight`?

Comment: It must be defined in `build` with `add_weight`.

Comment: So, in my case, given that it is defined outside `build`, it won't be saved with the usual methods `save`, etc.

Comment: Probably. I wouldn't try this. Who knows what other kinds of bugs may appear. Go for `build`.